# Copy named ranges to another workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, named-ranges

I have this VBA code to copy my named cells from one workbook to another, but it gives me `Error 9: Subscript out of range`. Any ideas please?

```
Sub namexfr()
 wbs = "C:\Users\MousaviM\Desktop\Book1.xlsm"
 wbd = "C:\Users\MousaviM\Desktop\Book2.xlsm"
 For Each nam In Workbooks(wbs).Names
  Workbooks(wbd).Names.Add Name:=nam.Name, RefersToR1C1:=nam.RefersToR1C1
 Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: The very last line before Next

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code with F8 in the VBA Editor? Does the error happen the first time it reaches that line, or does it loop through it a few times before the error occurs?

Comment: It doesn't loop through, I get the error the first time I reach the line. I found this code on this site, I am not very good at VBA. What does R1C1 reffer to? Is that the range that my named cells should be in?

Comment: Do the workbooks have (1) the same number of worksheets; and (2) do the sheets have the same names?

Comment: Yes, I just open two new workbooks to do this test. I called them Book1 and Book2 and both having Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3.

Comment: Sorry, I just added this in to a module and was able to see the error stops in the line "For Each nam In Workbooks(wbs).Names"

Comment: are there any named ranges in the workbook?

Comment: Yes, I added 3 named cells in book1 to see if I can transfer them to book2. I just want to do this test before I use the code in a live production workbook.

Answer (score 1):

So, the issue is that `Workbooks(wbs)` is not recognized as a Workbook object. This is because the argument in parentheses is expected to be an index, i.e., an integer, not a file path.

One solution is to loop through the Workbooks collection and compare your desired path to the paths of open workbooks. Then set a Workbook object equal to the matching workbook.

In the code below, I've done this for each workbook. Since you probably don't have a ton of workbooks open, the multiple loops are computationally insignificant.

```
Sub namexfr()
Dim wbs As Workbook, wbd As Workbook, wb As Workbook
wbspath = "C:\Users\MousaviM\Desktop\Book1.xlsm"
wbdpath = "C:\Users\MousaviM\Desktop\Book2.xlsm"
For Each wb In Workbooks
    If wb.FullName = wbspath Then
        Set wbs = wb
        Exit For
    End If
Next wb
For Each wb In Workbooks
    If wb.FullName = wbdpath Then
        Set wbd = wb
        Exit For
    End If
Next wb
For Each nam In wbs.Names
    wbd.Names.Add Name:=nam.Name, RefersToR1C1:=nam.RefersToR1C1
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I realized the first code would work if I eliminate the path and just have both workbooks open. But is there any way to choose which cell name to transfer and not all of them?

Comment: You would have to include your conditions inside the `For Each` loop through the names. It would be something like, IF nam meets conditions X, Y, Z, then add the duplicate name to `wbd`. Otherwise, skip it.

Comment: +1 Nice catch - I missed it. I'd have just replaced the `for each ...` with a `for each .. in wbs.names` but this solution seems more robust.